# Does a bootable OS X drive need more free space than the installer?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, disk-space

I made an 8GB partition on my HD to serve as a bootable OS X Yosemite drive, but it seems to still have 2.63GB free after [the bootable drive-making procedure](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html). Does the bootable drive need that space to be able to function properly, or can I bring it back into my startup disk partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made an installer image for OS X 10.10 to install in a virtual machine and it's only 5268873216 bytes or 4.90702 GB in Base2, in Base10 it's 5.27GB.  So you could have made it smaller.  Not sure if you can resize it, you can try and if not delete it and start with a smaller partition.  BTW There does need to a just a bit of free space as it's written to during the install.

Comment: Yeah, that "bit of free space" is what I'm wondering about. I'm sure stuff gets written as I screw around on the bootable drive, I'm just wondering exactly how much free space it needs.

Comment: It doesn't need much, the Install OS X Yosemite.app was 5173347593 bytes and the image was 5268873216 bytes.  So only 91.10033 MB (Base2) larger.  The calculations for the size was done by VMware Fusion.

Comment: What are Base2 and Base10 as far as disk space is concerned?

Comment: Generally speaking just so you have some understanding, Base2 is how the actual data is stored as it is after all a binary system, zero's and one's.  Base10 is what the manufacture uses to make the storage space look bigger.  Apple switched to that in Finder however from the CLI, like Terminal, it's still shown in Base2.   If you made it 5.4 GB in Disk Utility before you would have been fine.